# Ubuntu on nxp i.mx7d board

Tags: server, ubuntu-core

Google is recommending nxp i.mx7d board as a good choice for android things. Since I would like to run NodeRed on this device I need to install system that will support NodeRed.

Is it possible to flash this board with newest Ubuntu Core or Ubuntu Server? Is this device supported by Ubuntu?